# RSS feed only displays text

Tags: iphone, rss

I have an rss reader app which works perfectly on some feeds, but on others it just displays text and no images.

Is it the feed which should be adjusted to publish images or Im sure it is something with the way I read the stream.

Why does it work for some streams(shows entire posts, images, videos etc. from e.g. blogspot rss feeds) but not for other rss feeds?

I have read that the stream itself can be set to publish different content amounts.

How can I parse the feed so that all feeds will work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that it's due to the feed themselves... and not to the reader app.
Feed publisher can decide whether they want to include all or parts only of their content in their feeds (RSS or Atom). 
Then, even if they publish all the content, they may decide to publish it as raw text (just the text content) or full XHTML, which would allow the inclusion of images.

Unfortunately, there is little that you can do, except maybe ask the developer of your app to allow to show the original site/page and not just the feed entries.

Comment: Thanks I thought so. I did develop the app. What do you mean by showing the original page(resizing the content from the app side rather than making the website mobile supported), how would that be done differently? How is the data displayed? Is it just an xml parser and then set a UIWebView to the data content? how would the arrangement of the page be handled?thanks

Comment: This, or just add a button 'Open in Safari'.

Comment: This ? I want the display to be sized to the device, not scrolling, pinching and all that like with safari.

Comment: There is no perfect solution :) Either you show the text from the RSS feed, which won't be rich, or you show rich content (the actual content), but the user experience may not be as good on all devices...

Comment: I will ask the people to change their rss feed streams to publish all content. Thanks for your time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what are the differences between the feeds that work and the feeds that don't? What assumptions do you make about the RSS content, and in what situations are those assumptions not satisfied? When you run the code in the debugger, what do you see when you encounter a feed where images don't work? Also, what code? ;)